# How to break word after special character like Hyphens (-)

Tags: html, css, text

Given a relatively simple CSS:

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  12333-2333-233-23339392-332332323
</div>
```

> How do I make it so that the string stays constrained to the `width`
>   of **150**, and wraps to a new line on the *hyphen*?

Comment: Did this work for you?  i tried this in Firefox, and it completely removes the hyphen...

Comment: "this" meaning the ­ fix

Comment: @ChrisMarasti-Georg: There are six fixes as I type.

Comment: Big post: https://kenneth.io/blog/2012/03/04/word-wrapping-hypernation-using-css/

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Replace your hyphens with this:

```
&shy;
```

It's called a "soft" hyphen.

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  12333&shy;2333&shy;233&shy;23339392&shy;332332323
</div>
```

Comment: ... and it will not show up in the display unless there is an actual break there.  So it is no good if you always want the hyphen displayed.

Comment: I was wondering about the browser compatibility of `&shy;`. [According to Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/oddsandends/wbr.html) (see compatibility table), it does well, with the only issues arising in older browsers such as FF2 and IE5.5-6.

Answer (score 34):

In all modern browsers<sup>*</sup> (and in some [older browsers](http://www.quirksmode.org/oddsandends/wbr.html), too), the [`<wbr>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/wbr) is the perfect tool for providing the opportunity to break long words at specific points.

To quote from that link:

> The Word Break Opportunity (`<wbr>`) HTML element represents a position within text where the browser may optionally break a line, though its line-breaking rules would not otherwise create a break at that location.

Here's how it could be used to in the OP's example (or see it in action at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AdleyEskridge/qrgaK/)):

```
<div style="width: 150px;">
  12333-<wbr>2333-<wbr>233-<wbr>23339392-<wbr>332332323
</div>
```

<sup>*</sup>I've tested it in IE9, IE10, and the latest versions of Chrome, Firefox, and Opera, and Safari.

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  12333-<wbr>2333-<wbr>233-<wbr>23339392-<wbr>332332323
</div>
```

Answer (score 18):

As part of CSS3, it is not yet fully supported, [but you can find information on word-wrapping here](http://www.css3.info/preview/word-wrap/). Another option is the [wbr tag, &shy;, and &#8203;](http://www.quirksmode.org/oddsandends/wbr.html) none of which are fully supported either.

Comment: For the record `word-wrap: break-word;` doesn't break at the hyphen in Firefox (tested in v11)

Answer (score 8):

Your example works as expected in Google Chrome, Safari (Windows), and IE8. The text breaks out of the 150px box in Firefox 3 and Opera 9.5.

Additionally `&shy;` won't work for your example, as it will either:

- work when word-breaking but when not word-breaking not display any hyphens, or
- work when not word-breaking but display two hyphens when word-breaking
  since it adds a hyphen on a break.

Answer (score 8):

In this specific instance (where your string is going to contain hyphens) I'd transform the text to this server-side:

```html
<div style="width:150px;">
  <span>12333-</span><span>2333-</span><span>233-</span><span>23339392-</span><span>332332323</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This shouldn't make a difference, right?

Or, unless you put those spans on nowrap.

Answer (score 7):

Depending on what you want to see exactly, you can use a combination of `hyphen`, `soft hyphen`, and/or `zero width space`.

On a soft hyphen, your browser can word-break (adding an hyphen).
On a zero width space, your browser can word break (without adding anything).

Thus, if your code is something like :

`111111&shy;222222&shy;-333333&#8203;444444-&#8203;555555`

then your browser will show this with no word-break :

> 1111112222222-33333334444444-5555555

and this will every possible word-break :

> 111111-
>   222222-
>   -333333
>   444444-
>   555555

Just pick up the option you need. In your case, it may be the one between 4s and 5s.

Comment: Beware of browser incompatibilities. See the compatibility table here: http://www.quirksmode.org/oddsandends/wbr.html

Comment: Just a note, `&shy;` is by far the better option here. All the others break font text kerning, for instance.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use :

```
word-break:break-all;
```

ex.

```
<div style='width:10px'>ababababababbabaabababababababbabababa</div>
```

output:

```
abababababa
ababababbba
abbabbababa
ababb
```

word-break is break all the word or line even if no-space in sentence that not feets in provided width or height. nut for that you must be provide a width or height.

Answer (score 0):

The non-breaking hyphen works well.

**HTML Entity (decimal)**

```
&#8209;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `-` you can use `&hyphen;` or `\u2010`.

Also, make sure the **hyphens** css property was **not** set to *none* (The default value is *manual*).

`<wbr>` is not supported by *Internet Explorer*.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this may help

use `<br>`(break) tag where you want to break the line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 0 width space after hyphen character:

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  12333-&#8203;2333-&#8203;233-&#8203;23339392-&#8203;332332323
</div>
```

if You want line break before hyphen use `&#8203;-` instead.