# Most elegant way to force a TEXTAREA element to line-wrap, *regardless* of whitespace

Tags: javascript, html, css, text

Html Textarea elements only wrap when they reach a space or tab character. This is fine, until the user types a looooooooooooooooooooooong enough word. I'm looking for a way to strictly enforce line breaks (eg.: even if it results in "loooooooooooo \n ooooooooooong").

[image]

The best I've found is to add a zero-width unicode space after every letter, but this breaks copy and paste operations. Anyone know of a better way?

Note: I'm referring to the "textarea" element here (i.e.: the one that behaves similarly to a text input) - not just a plain old block of text.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The CSS settings `word-wrap:break-word` and `text-wrap:unrestricted` appear to be CSS 3 features.  Good luck finding a way to do this on current implementations.

Comment: just realized Facebook does a pretty good job with their forms, I'll have to get in there and see what they're doing. Either that or wait till browsers support the attributes you mention - breaks my hard to waste a thousand lines of javascript on something that will eventually be so easy

Comment: It won't be long (yeh yeh yeh yeh)! New developer features in Firefox 3.1 "word-wrap: This newly-supported property lets content specify whether or not lines may be broken within words in order to prevent overflow when an otherwise unbreakable string is too long to fit on one line."

Comment: Excellent!  I'm glad this is coming together fast; it's such a silly feature to be without.

Answer (score 8):

- quirksmode.org has an [overview of various methods](http://www.quirksmode.org/oddsandends/wbr.html).
- There's a related SO question: ["In HTML, how to word-break on a dash?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904/in-html-how-to-word-break-on-a-dash)
- In browsers that support it, [`word-wrap: break-word`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#word-wrap) might give the desired effect as well.

Answer (score 5):

Breaking long words at textarea width size:

**1) for modern browsers:**

```
textarea { word-break: break-all; }
```

**2) for IE8 compatibility add:**

```
textarea { -ms-word-break: break-all; }
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531184%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

**3) add IE11 compatibility hack:**

[Internet Explorer 11 word wrap is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20149715/internet-explorer-11-word-wrap-is-not-working)

```
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast:none) {
*::-ms-backdrop, textarea { white-space: pre; } 
}
```

---

This code it's working fine on:

-IE 11, Chrome 51, Firefox 46 (Windows 7);

-IE 8, Chrome 49, Firefox 18 (Windows Xp);

-Edge 12.10240 , Opera 30 (Windows 10);

Comment: `word-break: break-all` did it! tyvm

Answer (score 2):

There's the non-standard element wbr that is supported by at least

Firefox, http://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTML/Element

Internet Explorer, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535917(VS.85).aspx

and Opera.

Comment: afaik you can't go inserting html elements inside a textarea, so that won't work

Comment: You're right. But take a look at the revisions ...there was no "textarea" mentioned at this time ;)

Answer (score 1):

The most elegant way is to use `wrap="soft"` for wrapping entire words or `wrap="hard"` for wrapping by character or `wrap="off"` for not wrapping at all though the last one `wrap="off"` is often not needed as automatically the browser uses automatically as if it was `wrap="off"`.
EXAMPLE:

```
<textarea name="tbox" cols="24" rows="4" wrap="soft"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested the **<wbr>**, **&#8203;** and **&shy;** techniques. All three worked well in IE 7, Firefox 3 and Chrome.

The only one that did not break the copy/paste was the **<wbr>** tag.

Comment: afaik you can't go inserting html elements inside a textarea, so that won't work

Answer (score 0):

According to my tests, only Firefox has the described behavior among current browsers. So I guess your best bet is to wait for the imminent release of Firefox 3.1 to solve your problem :)