# Textarea to resize based on content length

Tags: javascript

I need a textarea where I type my text in the box, it grows in length as needed to avoid having to deal with scroll bars and it need to shrink after delete text!
I didn’t want to go down the mootools or jquery route because I have a lightweight form.

Comment: jQuery is lightweight as well. Don't reinvent the weel... At least, check the jQuery's solution and try copy it.

Comment: Grows in X or Y? (both doesn't make much sense) Constrained at all?

Comment: btw, SO should use one of these methods for comments :-)

Comment: I created a package for this if you are using react: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-fluid-textarea

Comment: textarea { display: table; }

Answer (score 310, accepted):

You can check the content's height by setting to `1px` and then reading the `scrollHeight` property:

```js
function textAreaAdjust(element) {
  element.style.height = "1px";
  element.style.height = (25+element.scrollHeight)+"px";
}
```

```html
<textarea onkeyup="textAreaAdjust(this)" style="overflow:hidden"></textarea>
```

It works under Firefox 3, IE 7, Safari, Opera and Chrome.

Comment: There's a problem in Firefox, if your user inputs a very long word (no white space, larger than the textarea) then "overflow:hidden" will prevent her from seeing the right end of the word. Other browsers don't care since they will line-break even without white spaces.

You can remedy to this by using "overflow-y:hidden" instead, but then your css is not standards-compliant.

Comment: Regarding the Firefox problem, it might be resolved soon: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47817/most-elegant-way-to-force-a-textarea-element-to-line-wrap-regardless-of-whites

Comment: If you textarea is too tall and generates scroll on the page **and** you happen to have your page scrolled down, this will reset the scroll position to the top when you 'height = 1px'. To avoid it you can assign the height to the textarea's parent temporarily.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.scrollHeight → "scrollHeight is part of the MSIE's DHTML object model. scrollHeight is not part of any W3C specification or technical recommendation." But it seems to work nevertheless: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#t36 However, note that it doesn't decrease the textarea size after it has been increased.

Comment: This is a very similar answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5346855/124946 If we set `height='auto'` right before setting it to `scrollHeight`, then it works as expected, shrinking as needed.

Comment: This small piece of code is doing the trick :-)
Really nice and fast when dealing with multiple textares in a page.

Comment: This is a much better solution (as far as being light-weight) than any I've seen, and I've been looking all over.  Thank you!

Comment: This has a problem when the textarea gets taller than the view port. In that case when the textarea grows it gets jittery. Otherwise quite nice.

Comment: jQuery solution (based on this):
`<textarea class="autoheight">[content]</textarea>`
    `$(function() {
        $('textarea.autoheight').each(function() {
        $(this).height(1);
        $(this).height(10 + $(this).get(0).scrollHeight);
      });
    });`

Comment: This is a good solution, but in some cases you may see the height shrink and expand every time a line break happens. One approach to avoid this would be to clone the element off screen somewhere and determine the correct height on the clone. In this way, you'll only be setting the target element's height once per keystroke.

Comment: it is not working for ie 10

Comment: So if I right click from the mouse and paste, the resize does not happen. I guess we could also use the mouse down event and have a similar action for that.

Comment: for angular 2+, el.target.style.height and el.target.scrollHeight

Comment: `You can check the content's height by setting to 1px and then reading the scrollHeight property` i find that part of the answer really intriguing, why scrollHeight does not give the correct content height without resetting the height first.. Added a separate question on that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68983541/why-do-we-set-textarea-height-to-0px-before-setting-it-equal-to-its-scrollheig.

Comment: this is not a particularly react friendly solution as reacts own internal rendering process might override styles set in js

Comment: This does not work reliably in Firefox 120 (MacOS): if you reload the page, it returns different values each time

Answer (score 75):

You may also try `contenteditable` attribute onto a normal `p` or `div`. Not really a `textarea` but it will auto-resize without script.

```css
.divtext {
    border: ridge 2px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 20em;
    min-height: 5em;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="divtext" contentEditable>Hello World</div>
```

Comment: this will, however, add all HTML rubbish when pasting.

Comment: See this answer to strip HTML rubbish: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20384452/59087

Comment: This solution is great if textarea is readonly. (That case contentEditable can be omitted) I would also add `white-space: pre;` setting.

Comment: Great solution! One improvement to make it more act like a textarea: I would add a cursor on hover the div box `.divtext:hover { cursor:text; }`. In my case I also modified the `.divtext:focus` class to change background color when focusing the text box.

Comment: still works in '19 with angular 7 and ngx-highlight `<pre><code contentEditable [textContent]="sqlContent"></code></pre>`

Comment: this solution breaks a11y, it should be avoided. Just use the normal textarea HTML tag

Answer (score 12):

Use this function:

```
function adjustHeight(el){
    el.style.height = (el.scrollHeight > el.clientHeight) ? (el.scrollHeight)+"px" : "60px";
}
```

Use this html:

```
<textarea onkeyup="adjustHeight(this)"></textarea>
```

And finally use this css:

```
textarea {
min-height: 60px;
overflow-y: auto;
word-wrap:break-word
}
```

The solution simply is letting the scrollbar appears to detect that height needs to be adjusted, and whenever the scrollbar appears in your text area, it adjusts the height just as much as to hide the scrollbar again.

Comment: i know that this is an old post but when I print the textarea, if the whole content does not fit in the first page, the whole contecnt goes to the second page and creates unwanted spaces on the first page. How can I split the textarea in two pages in printing?

Comment: For anyone with Dale's issue, there is css: `page-break-before:avoid`

Comment: @AnorZaken The newer property is `break-before` but that aside, it's not quite browser compatible. Support for some values is even missing in FF.

Comment: @aderchox Good point, and support is why it's still a good idea to continue using `page-break-before` - it has support from the stone age, and newer browsers treat it as an alias for `break-before`. However `avoid` is not supported on old FF unfortunately.

Answer (score 11):

A jquery solution has been implemented, and source code is available in github at: https://github.com/jackmoore/autosize .

Comment: Where exactly??

Comment: @KimHomann http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/ .

Comment: It doesn't adjust the height when you change the width using the bottom-right corner.

Comment: Post an issue over there rather than downvoting the answer. I'm not the author of that plugin to check or fix the issue.

Answer (score 6):

Alciende's answer didn't quite work for me in Safari for whatever reason just now, but did after a minor modification:

```
function textAreaAdjust(o) {
    o.style.height = "1px";
    setTimeout(function() {
        o.style.height = (o.scrollHeight)+"px";
    }, 1);
}
```

Hope this helps someone

Comment: Sure that's a great solution... if you want to strobe your textarea every time the user presses a key.  :V

Comment: This worked to solve my problem at the time. Today, I would probably use jackmoore's jQuery solution given in Ravimallya's answer

Answer (score 0):

Decide a width and check how many characters one line could hold, and then for each key pressed you call a function that looks something like:

```
function changeHeight()
{
var chars_per_row = 100;
var pixles_per_row = 16;
this.style.height = Math.round((this.value.length / chars_per_row) * pixles_per_row) + 'px';
}
```

Havn't tested the code.

Comment: It would work correctly only if font is monospaced. Also, textarea doesn't have "value" property.

Comment: this would also break down if the font size wasn't 16px

Comment: Pawka - textareas do have a 'value' DOM property.

Comment: This won't work when the user type "enter" onto the textarea

Comment: The code isn't tested and could of course be improved. And yes, the value of a textarea is the content within <textarea> and </textarea>.

Comment: The value attribute is separate from content.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any way to get width of texts in *variable-width* fonts, especially in javascript.

The only way I can think is to make a hidden element that has variable width set by css, put text in its innerHTML, and get the width of that element. So you may be able to apply this method to cope with textarea auto-sizing problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this by using a span and a textarea.

You have to update the span with the text in textarea each time the text is changed. Then set the css width and height of the textarea to the span's clientWidth and clientHeight property.

Eg:

```
.textArea {
    border: #a9a9a9 1px solid;
    overflow: hidden;
    width:  expression( document.getElementById("spnHidden").clientWidth );
    height: expression( document.getElementById("spnHidden").clientHeight );
}
```

Comment: CSS expressions have been deprecated http://stackoverflow.com/a/6191696/179581