# overflow:auto changes internal div element width

Tags: css

**HTML:**

```
<div id="jhjhssed" class="hhsfjhjruweyr" id="fhsdjfhsss" style="">
    <div class='bubble5'>Andrew Stockard
        <img src='Status-tray-online-icon (1).png' class='onlinecircle' />
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.bubble5 {
    position: relative;
    top: -27px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-left: 51px;
    width: auto; 
}
.hhsfjhjruweyr {
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
    color: #000;
    font-family: Arial;
    border-top: 1px solid #8d8d8d;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.hhsfjhjruweyr:hover {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.onlinecircle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    right: 5px;
}
```

The problem is that when i hover the scroll bar shows up as expected but when i unhover the width of all the elements in the div with the id `jhjhssed` changes. by changes i mean it it becomes smaller to fit the scrollbar on next hover.. what i want is... the width changing on showing scrollbar is fine but i want it to return to 100% width when the scrollbar is no longer visible i even tried adding `width:100%` to the div `jhjhssed` but it does not work.. how can i do this...

**No scrollbar:**

[image]

**Scrollbar:**

[image]

**After scrollbar was present:**

[image]

**What it should look like:**

[image]

hope i was able to make myself clear..

Comment: create http://jsfiddle.net/ please

Comment: Humthis is avery commonissue. Solution 1alwaysshow scrolbar :height :101%. Solution 2 use javascript to change css. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548465/prevent-scroll-bar-from-adding-up-to-the-width-of-page-on-chrome

Comment: You have two `id` attributes on your outer div. I'm sure that will create problems for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution most compatible with various browsers will probably involve using JavaScript.

My favorite, cross-browser JavaScript library being jQuery, I would recommend the following solution:

```
$('.hhsfjhjruweyr').mouseout(function(){
    $(this).css('overflow-y', 'hidden');
});
```

BTW, where did you get a class name like "hhsfjhjruweyr"?

Comment: i was able to solve that problem using a bit of java script now i have another question how do you disable scrolling permanently for a webpage..?