# How to avoid any offset from a scrollbar in dynamic pages in HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a dynamic page, in HTML/CSS using Javascript and jQuery. The height of this page can change, and a scrollbar can appear or disappear. Also, I want the content to be centered. To achieve that, I use `margin: 0 auto;`. But when the scrollbar shows itself (or hides itself), the page moves a little on the side.

How can I prevent it from moving left and right ?

**EDIT**

Here's a jsfiddle to see what the problem is (sorry, the content is in French): 
http://jsfiddle.net/r4jspomr/

You can click on the titles to extend/retract the content under it

Comment: Please provide the code and JSFiddle example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent scroll-bar from adding-up to the Width of page on Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548465/prevent-scroll-bar-from-adding-up-to-the-width-of-page-on-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

it is default Behavior of browsers, you can disable scrollbar using the following code and then use a beautiful custom-scrollbar like [this](http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/examples/complete_examples.html)

```
$("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
```

Comment: I had already guessed that it was their default behavior. I was wondering if there was a workaround that did not imply using a custom scrollbar

Comment: @Bosion: maybe you find a solution, but there are many browsers with different behaviors