# Horizontal scrollbar in Chrome with direction RTL

Tags: css, google-chrome, right-to-left

On Chrome there is a horizontal scrollbar on a page with direction rtl in combination with `margin-right: auto` and `overflow: auto` even though there is no margin and no content.

For an example, see https://jsfiddle.net/ht3drjae/2/. I would expect to see no green background color and no horizontal scrollbar as inner and outer should have the same width.

The scrollbar is only there on Chrome, but not on Firefox or IE. So why is the scrollbar there? Is this a browser bug?

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    direction: rtl;
}
.outer {
    height: 500px;
    overflow: auto;
    background: green;
}
.inner {
    height: 1000px;
    margin-right: auto;
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: I'm thinking it's because of the scrollbar on the left causing the extra width.  This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548465/prevent-scroll-bar-from-adding-up-to-the-width-of-page-on-chrome

Comment: scrollbars do not increase element width, their widht is substracted from the element content width. "Any space taken up by the scrollbars should be taken out of (subtracted from the dimensions of) the containing block formed by the element with the scrollbars." http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#overflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it's a bug:

> 10.3.3 Block-level, non-replaced elements in normal flow
>
> The following constraints must hold among the used values of the other
>   properties:
>
> 'margin-left' + 'border-left-width' + 'padding-left' + 'width' +
>   'padding-right' + 'border-right-width' + 'margin-right' = width of
>   containing block
>
> If 'width' is not 'auto' and 'border-left-width' + 'padding-left' +
>   'width' + 'padding-right' + 'border-right-width' (plus any of
>   'margin-left' or 'margin-right' that are not 'auto') is larger than
>   the width of the containing block, then any 'auto' values for
>   'margin-left' or 'margin-right' are, for the following rules, treated
>   as zero.
>
> If all of the above have a computed value other than 'auto', the
>   values are said to be "over-constrained" and one of the used values
>   will have to be different from its computed value. If the 'direction'
>   property of the containing block has the value 'ltr', the specified
>   value of 'margin-right' is ignored and the value is calculated so as
>   to make the equality true. If the value of 'direction' is 'rtl', this
>   happens to 'margin-left' instead.
>
> If there is exactly one value specified as 'auto', its used value
>   follows from the equality.
>
> If 'width' is set to 'auto', any other 'auto' values become '0' and
>   'width' follows from the resulting equality.
>
> If both 'margin-left' and 'margin-right' are 'auto', their used values
>   are equal. This horizontally centers the element with respect to the
>   edges of the containing block.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#blockwidth

For you example, the computed values for `.inner` are

```
margin-left: 0 (initial value)
border-left-width: 0 (because boder-style initial value is none)
padding-left: 0 (initial value)
width: auto (initial value)
padding-right: 0 (initial value)
border-right-width: 0 (because boder-style initial value is none)
margin-right: auto
```

So what should occur is:

> If 'width' is set to 'auto', any other 'auto' values become '0' and
>   'width' follows from the resulting equality.

`.inner` width should have same width as its parent and thus no horizontal scrollbar should appears.

If we also changes `direction` to `ltr` and `margin-left:auto` or `margin-right:auto` it does not occurs, so it looks like the issue occurs only when the direction is rtl.

Comment: I think you're right and that it's a bug in Chrome. I will file a bug report and see if they want to fix it. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set direction: ltr on your body tag, wrap the whole content of page in a div and set its direction to rtl.

Comment: I ran into the same problem, and this fix worked perfectly!

Comment: This works, thank you! But it might be really a Chrome bug. Firefox works as expected

Answer (score 0):

I hope the below code can solve the issue:

```
.outer {
    height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;/changed to hidden/
    background: green;
}

overflow:hidden;
```

and its always better to use direction with html markup like

instead with CSS declaration.