# cannot get full width of page and image divs arent sized properly

Tags: html, css, width, padding

I've put a codepen example to explain:

http://codepen.io/djnutron/pen/gPJzGJ

Basically, I'm wondering why the html and body tags will not go full width. My screen is 1920x1080, but the html tag refuses to be 1920 - it always goes to 1903 for some reason? Any idea why? Also the parent div of the img tag is adding some padding somewhere - because the img is 1900 wide and the surrounding div goes to 1903? Im wondering where this padding is coming from? Ive tried adding display:block, and also vertical-align:top to the image, but no dice...

Here's the code:

HTML

```
<div class="gallery"  >
  <div class="gallery-cell">
    <div class="innerG">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/animals-q-c-1900-850-2.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-cell">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.gallery-cell {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: I cannot see any padding and I cannot fully understand that you want to aim, you want your img to be full screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is the case:

> The scrollbar is 17 pixels wide

Also the div you have called "innerG" is display block, so it has the width of the full page. No padding is hidden anywhere. :)

*Just zoom out and you will see that it's size is changing to match the screen width*

Comment: Where is the scrollbar coming from? Is this part of the codepen site? Its weird because their body/html tag works correctly at 1920 in my browser - whereas my html body shows 1903???

Comment: This is the correct answer. How are we supposed to work around the scrollbar being introduced?

Comment: Is this perhaps the answer? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548465/prevent-scroll-bar-from-adding-up-to-the-width-of-page-on-chrome

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have full `body` width all the time, you can set this in CSS:

```
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 1920px;
}
```

Comment: I would like it to be percentage not fixed - hence would like to use 100% but it's not working - still 1903px

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set both your HTML and Body to `width: 100%;`

Is there any content that is longer than the window's height? If so, might be the scroll bar as Silviagreen said.

Comment: It wont go to 100% - still 1903 pixels ... :/