# How to ignore a scrollbar width in CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

## Explanation

[image]

I want to line up three boxes in one line horizontally but the last one falls down.

[image]

When I remove the scrollbar, it lines up fine.

So, the problem is caused by the scrollbar width.

How can I ignore the scrollbar width in css?

Do I need to write JavaScript code to calculate the scrollbar width and adjust the width of the wrapper dom element?

## DEMO & CODE

I posted html and css code in codePen.io.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kXAPap

### HTML

```
<div id="main">

    <ul id="window-list">

        <li class="window">
            <div class="window-thumbnail">
            </div>
        </li><!--

        --><li class="window">
            <div class="window-thumbnail">
            </div>
        </li><!--

        --><li class="window">
            <div class="window-thumbnail">
            </div>
        </li><!--

        --><li class="window">
            <div class="window-thumbnail">
            </div>
        </li><!--

        --><li class="window">
            <div class="window-thumbnail">
            </div>
        </li>


    </ul>

</div>
```

### CSS

```
body {
    border-top: solid 1px #a3a1a3;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
}

ul, li, p {

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

}

/*
1px(border-left) + 30px(padding-left) + 158px(width) + 18px(margin-right) + 158px(width) + 18px(margin-right) + 158px(width) + 30px(padding-right) + 1px(border-right) = 572px
*/

#main {
    width: 572px;
}


#window-list {

    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: solid 1px #b8b8b8;
    width: 510px;
    height: 350px;
    margin: 0 0 8px 0;
    overflow: scroll; /*This line causes the problem*/
    padding: 10px 30px;
    list-style-type: none;


}

.window {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 18px 18px 0;


}

.window:nth-child(3n) {

    margin-right: 0;

}

.window-thumbnail {

    margin: 0 0 8px 0;
    height: 158px;
    width: 158px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
}
```

Comment: I see 5 boxes, not 3.

Comment: also, do you absolutely HAVE to give these boxes a fixed width?

Comment: I mean I want to line up 3 boxes in one line.

Comment: I think so! I want to imitate this layout. https://inteygrate.com/content/images/2016/05/Screen-Shot-2016-05-30-at-5-28-17-PM-1.png

Comment: I'll provide a code snippet in my answer...

Comment: [Aligning Three Divs Horizontally Using Flexbox](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32122011/3597276)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent scroll-bar from adding-up to the Width of page on Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18548465/prevent-scroll-bar-from-adding-up-to-the-width-of-page-on-chrome)

Answer (score 4):

One way to do it in pure CSS is to make the scroll bar invisible completely. This will still allow scrolling.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar { 
display: none; 
}
```

You can also use jQuery to achieve exactly what you wanted:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var body = $('body');
    var normalwidth = 0;
    var scrollwidth = 0;
    if(body.prop('scrollHeight')>body.height()){
        normalwidth = window.innerWidth;
        scrollwidth = normalwidth - body.width();
        $('#main').css({marginRight:'-'+scrollwidth+'px'});
    }
});
```

And you can hide the horizontal scroll using:

```
body {
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

[Here's a jsfiddle made by Lwym](http://jsfiddle.net/NQAzt/).
I suggest you check out his [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18548909/6679116) too.

Comment: Permanently enabling the scrollbar, by `overflow-x:scroll`, is better than hiding it, because the scrollbar indicates a lot about the visible part of the list, such as where in the list, what part of the list, and greyed if it is the whole list. No-trivial visual clues. Plus the scrollbar can be used for fine mouse control.

Comment: [Not supported by firefox](https://caniuse.com/#search=-webkit-scrollbar) though.

Answer (score 1):

Unless it is a business requirement to give these boxes a fixed, I would strongly recommend you to give them a variable width using percentage units which will make your document more responsive to different viewport widths and screen sizes.

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.container .box {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ddd;
  width: 28%;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 20px 0 20px 4%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div><!--
  --><div class="box"></div><!--
  --><div class="box"></div><!--
  --><div class="box"></div><!--
  --><div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

#### Things to note

1- This solution is 99% CSS2-compatible...some features will degrade gracefully such as the border-radius which is currently supported by all major browsers out there

2- you said it doesn't need to be responsive because it's a chrome extension. Well, it does because desktops come in a lot of screen sizes. So, it is responsive

3- I've given the boxes a fixed height to make them look uniform but if you want a variable height you can wrap the boxes in containers with a group of 3 boxes each

Comment: It's a chrome extension, so I don't need to make it responsive. It's used only on Desktop.

Comment: @Hayatomo you DO need to make it responsive because not all desktops have the same screen size

Comment: I'm going to draw a window thumbnail image in canvas inside the div elements with ".window-thumbnail". When I draw the thumbnail image which I screencapture programmatically, I need to specify the width and height. I'm not sure if the image drawn in canvas can be responsive as well.

Comment: @Hayatomo of course it can, but you will have to use javascript to dynamically resize the canvas element

Comment: For different desktop sizes: not only that, but of course: simply resized windows! For one, I hardly ever maximize a browser window; I have other things to share my limited (never big enough) screen estate with.

Comment: @hytm: images can also be dynamically resized simply by CSS, I did the same in my own picture viewer. (You can even use [various units](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp) relative to the current viewport (window) size.)

Answer (score 1):

If these have to be fixed, I would highly recommend using flex for this. Here is your CSS using Flex:

```
body {
    border-top: solid 1px #a3a1a3;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
}

ul, li, p {

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

}

/*
1px(border-left) + 30px(padding-left) + 158px(width) + 18px(margin-right) + 158px(width) + 18px(margin-right) + 158px(width) + 30px(padding-right) + 1px(border-right) = 572px
*/

#main {
    width: 572px;
}


#window-list {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: solid 1px #b8b8b8;
    width: 510px;
    height: 350px;
    margin: 0 0 8px 0;
    overflow: scroll; /*This line causes the problem*/
    padding: 10px 30px;
    list-style-type: none;


}

.window {
    margin: 0 18px 18px 0;


}

.window:nth-child(3n) {

    margin-right: 0;

}

.window-thumbnail {

    margin: 0 -6px 8px 0;
    height: 158px;
    width: 158px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
}
```

Here is a working example: http://codepen.io/jsanatar/pen/xOyLWK

Comment: You changed the width and height of ".window-thumbnail" in your example code from 158px to 150px. When I set the width and height to the original value, the third box falls down.

Comment: Can I take out some of the margin / padding? That is the only way these are going to work. Also, this is just desktop right? It won't look right for mobile. Anyway, updating my example now.

Comment: Hayatomo, fixed this example by removing some of the margin. This flex example should work on all devices. I left all the sizes as is.

Answer (score 1):

Here, http://codepen.io/bhshawon/pen/OXBjOg

Using negative value for margin-right of every 3rd child

```
.window:nth-child(3n) {

    margin-right: -16px;

}
```

Comment: This will cause responsive issues on smaller phones.

Comment: What's the reason you give "16"? How did you get the number?

Comment: Seeing he used fixed pixel value for everything, I doubt it will cause anymore problem than it's already there. If he does convert everything using percent/em value, he can also use the negative margin using percent/em value. @JosephSanatar

Comment: @Hayatomo It's the lowest value that solves it. I tried 20 first, then decremented from there.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
overflow: overlay
```

see details in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

Comment: This is an experimental feature not supported in Firefox or Safari as of today.