Layout inconsistency when switching between pages with different scrollbar widths and Layouts
I'm encountering a layout inconsistency issue when transitioning between two pages in my React application. The homepage features three columns with fixed heights, ensuring that the inner content scrolls independently. However, on the rankings page, which also has a fixed header like the homepage but allows the main content to scroll relative to the whole body, a scrollbar appears, causing a slight jump in the page width when switching between these pages.
I have created a codesandbox demo for your reference. Here's a simplified version of my code structure:
App.js
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Home";
import Rankings from "./Rankings";
import Header from "./Header";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="app-container">
        <Header />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/rankings" element={<Rankings />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

Home.js
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./home.css";
import NewsFeed from "./NewsFeed";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="main-content">
      <div className="background"></div>
      <div className="grid-container">
        <div className="col-container" style={{ background: "pink" }}>
          <NewsFeed />
        </div>
        <div className="col-container" style={{ background: "orange" }}>
          <NewsFeed />
        </div>
        <div className="col-container" style={{ background: "red" }}>
          <NewsFeed />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

NewsFeed.js
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "./newsfeed.css";

function NewsFeed() {
  return (
    <div className="news-feed-container">
      <div className="news-feed-title">News Feed</div>
      <div className="news-items-container">
        <div className="news-item">News Item 1</div>
        <div className="news-item">News Item 2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default NewsFeed;

Rankings.js
import "./rankings.css";
export default function Rankings() {
  return (
    <div className="rankings-container">
      <div className="rankings-content">
        <div className="heading">
          <nav className="navigation">
            <ul className="menu">
              <li className="menu-item">Currency Ranking</li>
              <li className="menu-item">User Ranking</li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>

        <div className="flex flex-col">
          <div className="ranking-tables">
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime
              mollitia, molestiae quas vel sint commodi repudiandae consequuntur
              voluptatum laborum numquam blanditiis harum quisquam eius sed odit
              fugiat iusto fuga praesentium optio, eaque rerum! Provident
              similique accusantium nemo autem.
            </p>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime
              mollitia, molestiae quas vel sint commodi repudiandae consequuntur
              voluptatum laborum numquam blanditiis harum quisquam eius sed odit
              fugiat iusto fuga praesentium optio, eaque rerum! Provident
              similique accusantium nemo autem.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

Based on the provided Code for the NewsFeed component and the layout of the Rankings component, I have tried several approaches but am still stuck. I've explored adjusting the CSS styling in the CSS files, particularly focusing on the rankings page styles. However, despite my efforts, the issue persists.
I want to emphasize that I don't want to modify my main layout, although I'm open to any suggestions or insights that might help resolve this issue. How can I ensure a consistent layout when transitioning between these pages, regardless of the scrollbar presence? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Since the layout inconsistency is caused by appearance of scrollbar, there's two approaches you can take:
Force Scrollbar Visibility: Scrollbar is always visible, even when there's not enough content to scroll. This will prevent the layout shift when transitioning between pages.
Set Body Overflow: Set overflow-y property of the body element to scroll or auto in your CSS.
Basically, you need to do this in your index.css (assuming filename from codesandbox you shared):
body {
  overflow-y: auto; /* Force vertical scrollbar */
}

/* Alternatively, you can use 'auto' */
/*
body {
  overflow-y: scroll; 
}
*/


I forced a scrollbar on the body and now it appears on each page. It solved the issue of width. and now the transition is smooth. Although, there is an empty scroll width created on non-scrollable pages.

There are couple of approaches to handle this (width: 100vw, scrollbar-gutter: stable). I recommend you to follow this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70360664/13648595
