# Alternative For Replacing CSS expression for IE10 and above version

Tags: css, internet-explorer-10, css-expressions

I have an old ASP web application,which is riddled with CSS expressions.

They appear in the CSS file:

```
 #tabtreeDiv
 {
    position:absolute;
    top:expression((imageOffset + 23) + 'px');
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:expression((top.document.body.clientHeight - 49 - imageOffset) + 'px');
    clip:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:#FFFAE3;
 }
```

As 'expression' is not supported in IE10 and above versions,
Does anyone have a suggestion?
Any alternative for the same?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191679/css-expressions)

Comment: Depending on what exactly you are trying to do (hard to tell from the example), [calc()](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc) might be an option.

Comment: Need working full example and there is no `imageOffset` DOM node property. Are this expressions really working?

Answer (score 1):

possibly you can use the combination of CSS & Javascript to avoid expression in CSS