# Create css rules dynamically from element attributes

Tags: angularjs, css, sass, less

Went though SASS/LESS documentation, but could not find anything that I am looking for. I am working on an AngularJS app, which has loads of dynamic, predefined styling (think CMS).

Is it possible with CSS3/LESS/SASS/Anything to create CSS rules dynamically from a element attribute - in the browser?

I know I could do in-line styling, but I am not really comfortable with it - there must be a better way!

From the following HTML

`<div id="el" animation-time="3"></div>`

Create following css:
`#el { transition: 3s linear all; }`

I have seen some examples on-line of the following usage, so my hopes are high:

```
#container {
   min-width: 600px;
   width:expression(document.body.clientWidth < 600? "600px": "auto" );
}
```

Comment: So you're not comfortable with inline styles but you're perfectly fine with `font-size="32"`?

Comment: @BoltClock inline styling feels like I am back in 1995 ;) I completely understand the amount of code is the same, but I am planning to do some CSS animations etc.. so variable for LENGTH as an attribute would be perfect.

Comment: -1 css shall style html. Use html to style css to style html is a bad idea.

Comment: @PeterRader - whether is best practice or not is complicity separate discussion ;)

Comment: You seem to have mistaken inline style attributes for the `<font>` tag. It's the latter that dates back to 1995. The former didn't appear until '96/'97, and hardly anybody used it until as recently as the early 2000s when CSS started becoming the in thing. Either way I don't buy your argument - if it feels so archaic, why are you trying to replicate it anyway?

Comment: @cimmanon Ohh sorry, I wasnt aware..

Comment: @BoltClock - font size might not have been a perfect example here, something to do with animation would better fit what I am planning to use it with. Putting best practice a side, is this even possible?

Comment: @BoltClock - unless I go with inline css, I will have to create 100+ cases in my CSS (animations durations, animation directions, different animation styles etc..), which will never get used - feels wasteful.

Comment: Your latest question update seems to resemble the `data-*` attributes to some extent. But even with them you cannot directly use them to manipulate CSS props. You would have to use JS and that to me seems like over-complicating things.

Comment: @Iladarsda If its not best-practice i will neither vote down or up. But if its misuse i respectfully vote it down.

Comment: I really have to question here as to why this is even necessary.  How can only one specific instance require a single special style?  Placing style information in your markup leads to a maintenance nightmare.  Whether it's inline CSS, font tags, or something that looks like and smells like but isn't quite a font tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a list like this:

```
*[font-size="0pt"] {font-size:0pt}
*[font-size="1pt"] {font-size:1pt}
*[font-size="2pt"] {font-size:2pt} ...
```

Autor's note to comments:

- +100 which will never get used - feels wasteful.

Answer (score 0):

You must identify the HTMLNode. So this may work:

```
<div id="foobar" animation-time="3s"></div>
```

With

```
 div#foobar{
   transition-duration: expression(foobar.getAttribute('animation-time'));
 }
```

Comment: I dont think this will help while you need a unique id in the css.

Comment: CSS expression doesn't work everywhere:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191679/css-expressions