# can javascript be written in SCSS file like it does in LESS?

Tags: css, sass, less

I have seen in a tutorial http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/09/an-introduction-to-less-and-comparison-to-sass/, that we can write javascript inside less file, I wanted to know is it also possible to write javascript in scss files ?

Comment: Judging by how the comparison of LESS and SASS says that it is a feature of LESS, without mentioning SASS, I would imagine it is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

No.  JavaScript is not valid SCSS or SASS (indented) syntax.  Sass has its own "language" and it *only* compiles to CSS.

You *could* use the [deprecated CSS expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191679/css-expressions), but I don't recommend it.

Comment: Yes you are correct that SASS compile to css, but I am concerned how the link http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/09/an-introduction-to-less-and-comparison-to-sass/, in sectoon "JAVASCRIPT EVALUATION" shows [ @string: `'howdy'.toUpperCase()`; /* @string becomes 'HOWDY' */ ]. toUpperCase() is a js function.

Comment: Uh huh, that's LESS, not Sass.  Almost all of the examples on that page are LESS.