# Textarea auto resizer resize at every keypress on chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I'm implementing an auto textarea resizer that auto-expands a textarea when user presses ENTER and after a minimum scrollHeight size.

It works well in IE, Firefox and Opera, but not in Chrome.
In Chrome the textarea is resized at any keypress (not only ENTER) because when settings e.style.height it also changes scrollHeight (this doesn't happen to occur on other browsers.

I marked the problematic line with a comment:

```
function resize(e)
{
    e = e.target || e;
    var $e = $(e);

    console.log( 'scrollHeight:'+e.scrollHeight );
    console.log( 'style.height:'+e.style.height );

    var h = Math.min( e.scrollHeight, $e.data('textexp-max') );
    h = Math.max( h, $e.data('textexp-min') );

    if( $e.data('h')!=h )
    {
        e.style.height = "";
        e.style.height      =  h + "px"; //this changes the scrollHeight even if style.height is smaller thatn scrollHeight
        //e.style.overflow  = (e.scrollHeight > h ? "auto" : "hidden");
        $e.data('h',h);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Here you'll find full code: http://jsfiddle.net/NzTYd/9/

**UPDATE**
I've found that when I update the `e.style.height` in Firefox/IE/Opera, `e.scrollHeight` is updated to the exact same value:
Example:
Setting **80px** to `e.style.height`, sets to **80px** `e.scrollHeight`

However, Chrome updates `e.scrollHeight` with a higher value (4px more).
Example::
Settings **80px** to `e.style.height`, sets to **84px** `e.scrollHeight`

This causes a textarea that is growing 4px for EVERY keypress it receives!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the answer to this here.

[Textarea to resize based on content length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995168/textarea-to-resize-based-on-content-length)

Comment: That link shows different approaches to implement a textarea expander, but none is similar to mine.

Comment: I updated my question to a better description of the main problem

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found there is a bug with webkit: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=34224

Finally I solve it detecting if `e.scrollHeight` changed an amount of only 4 px, which is the difference chrome is adding.
If that condition is arised, I substract 4px from `e.style.height` to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I built an auto-expanding textarea in jQuery a few months back and haved used it with great success on many sites.  This doesn't address your issue directly, but you might find it helpful.

If the user provides a @@ a paragraph is inserted and extra line breaks are removed.

I have my textarea set to fit 40 characters per line. The line increments 1px at a time to accommodate the new characters.

You can see a working example on my site at evikjames.com > jQuery examples > Expandable Textarea.

```
$(".Expandable").live("keyup", function() {
    // ADJUST ROWS ROWS
    var ThisText = $(this).val();
    var Rows = calculateRows(ThisText);
    $(this).attr("rows", Rows);

    // CALCULTE COUNTER
    var ThisTextMax = $(this).attr("max");
    if (ThisText.length > ThisTextMax) {
        ThisText = ThisText.substring(ThisText, ThisTextMax);
        $(this).val(ThisText);
        alert("You have exceeded the maximum allowable text. Revise!");
    }
    $(this).next(".Count").html(ThisText.length + "/" + ThisTextMax + " characters.");
});

var calculateRows = function calculateRows(String) {
var NumCharacters = String.length;
var NumRows = Math.ceil(NumCharacters/40);
var Match = String.match(/@@/g);
var NumParagraphs = 0;
if (Match != null) {
     NumParagraphs = String.match(/@@/g).length;
     NumRows = NumRows + NumParagraphs;
}
return NumRows;
```

}

Comment: I'll take a look at your implementation. Thanks ;)