# Resizeable textarea that resizes constantly on keyup instead of waiting for content to overflow

Tags: javascript, css, resize, textarea

I'm trying to make a Message Contact Form with a textarea that automatically resizes according to the content inserted. I.e. as the user types in the message, the textarea resizes to fit the message.

For this, I was searching StackOverflow and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995168/textarea-to-resize-based-on-content-length).

However, when implementing the JavaScript snippet used there I get a textarea that resizes constantly, upon every `keyup` action. This is happening when I set the textarea to update with CSS easing. If I just let it resize with no "jaggedly", everything goes fine... but looks less elegant.

**[You can see what's going on here, in this jsFiddle I've worked up.](http://jsfiddle.net/7hkfL/)**

Perhaps somebody out there can see what's going on here!

Comment: Is the Java or HTML?  Note JavaScript and Java are not the same things

Comment: I seem to have pressed Enter on that tag too soon. Fixed it. Sorry about that. (It's javascript.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You better use a jquery plugin for resizing height of the textarea. I personally recommend this: **http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize**