# Words highlight on mouse over

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Do you know the most efficient way to highlight word and add onmouseover event?

I have text and I want to make somekind of word explanation field, so when user put his cursor on the word, I call AJAX to dictionary and show him meaning.

I have two ideas:
1) Before showing text, put each word to `<span onmouseon="my_foo("word");">` wrapper.
For example:

`<span onmouseon="my_foo("Hello");">Hello</span>`
`<span onmouseon="my_foo("world");">world</span>`

But I think this will seriously overload the page.

2) When user hold cursor for more than 0.5 sec in one area, I get pointer coordinates, calcuate what word is shown (I do not know if is possible) and do AJAX call.

What do you think is better, more easier to code?

Comment: I don't think 2 is possible because of differences between font rendering in different browsers. you would never know exactly which word it was. I would wrap everything either server side. or onLoad wrap everything in spans. On hover of any span with that class would ajax call

Comment: 2 is possible. But you will face issues for different browsers. I did implemented an annotation functionality same way. It was tough. for 1, there is a better way inside the event function definition you can get the inner text of the span so you do not need to put the string inside each call.

Comment: What about performance in case 1? Was it fine? I mean text of 5000 words, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First highlight the word under the cursor then show the meaning of it, check my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/shahe_masoyan/z7nkU/1/

**HTML**

```
    <div>
        <span>This text is a test text</span>
    </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('div').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.html($this.text().replace(/\b(\w+)\b/g, "<span>$1</span>"));
});

$('div span').hover(
    function() { 
        $(this).css('background-color','#ffff66'); 
        alert(getTheMeaningOfTheWord($(this).html()));
    },
    function() { 
        $(this).css('background-color',''); 
    }
);

function getTheMeaningOfTheWord(word){

    return word+' = theMeaning';
}
```

Comment: Do I need to refresh DOM or something else. I did as trial:
<span id="word_text_xx_N" class="word_in_text" onmouseover="console.log(\'aa\');">some</span>   And onmouseover work, but hover not.

Comment: you don't need to refresh anything, did you run the fiddle?

Comment: @Tigran see my code in the fiddle, I don't have any onmouseover function on my span

Comment: Will it work, in iframe? I tried you code. I already separated to spans and give class name. So I use: $('word_in_text').hover(). May be I did someting wrong, but will it work, in iframe?

Comment: `$('word_in_text')` is invalid jquery selector, you have to put the id of the span or the element like this: `$('#word_in_text')`. Can you show me your code in a fiddle?

Comment: I am not sure that it will work, too many js libraries. And my problem is when I put it into TinyMCE. If I put it into main page - no problem. Onmouse works fine, but non your solution, even css class style do not work.

Comment: I am sorry, I can't help you with TinyMCE, but as you see in the fiddle the works fine and as you requested, anyways, good luck finding a solution.

Comment: I found a solution and the problem was that TinyMCP loaded content dinimically and it strange way. JQuery did not look inside frame. That is solution: $($(document).contents().find('iframe').contents().find('.word_in_text')).hover(....
Thank you!

Comment: @Tigran Good to know that you found a solution :) Hachogh

Answer (score 1):

I think 1 is simple and can be done this way:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9d227/

**HTML**

```
<div id="yourDiv" style="Display: none;">your Text Here</div>
<div id="yourActualDiv"></div>
```

**JQuery**

```
var wordArray = $('#yourDiv').html().split(' ');
var totalString = "";
for(var i=0;i<wordArray.length;i++)
    totalString += "<span>" + wordArray[i] + " </span>";
$('#yourActualDiv').html(totalString);
var ConcurrenyFlag = 0;
$('#yourActualDiv span').mouseover(
    function()
    {
       if(ConcurrenyFlag == 0)
       {
           ConcurrenyFlag = 1;
           // Your code here.
           ConcurrenyFlag = 0;
       }
    }
)
```

This way, you only need to put your text in the `yourDiv`. The javascript code will handle the rest for you.
Hope this helps you.

**The `ConcurrenyFlag` will help in reducing the load on client as only one code part will run at a time.**

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do something close to what you're looking for.

```
$('.addWordDictionary').html('<span>'+$('.addWordDictionary').html().replace(/ {1,}/g, '</span> <span>')+'</span>');
```

But, as you said it may be client intensive especially if there is a lot of text.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Lettering.js to solve this

http://letteringjs.com/

Simplified example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Zzxpx/

HTML:

```
<div class="w">"You will die of suffocation, in the icy cold of space"<div>
```

JS:

```
$(".w").lettering('words');
```

Answer (score 1):

I've made this stuff : http://jsfiddle.net/wared/eAq9k/. Requires a textarea and works by clicking instead of hovering. More details about `getCaret()` here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/263796/1636522.

```html
<textarea readonly>Lorem ipsum</textarea>
```

```css
textarea {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    resize: none;
    outline: none;
    margin: .5em 0;
}
```

```js
$(function () {
    var el = $('textarea'),
        text = el.text();
    el.click(function () {
        var i = getCaret(this),
            w = getWord(text, i);
        $('p').text(i + ' : "' + w + '"');
    });

    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/995374/1636522

    el[0].style.height = '1px';
    el[0].style.height = 25 + el[0].scrollHeight + 'px';
});

function getWord(s, i) {
    var r = /\s/g;
    while (i && !r.test(s[--i])) {}
    r.lastIndex = i && ++i;
    return s.slice(i, (
        r.exec(s) || { index: s.length }
    ).index);
}
```