# Textarea Autoheight CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a textarea that will hold data from a database.  It will be disabled so that the user cannot interact with it.

Is there  a way to set the height via css so that it fits the area.  IE: if there is only one line of text, the textarea height is only 1 row or if there is 3 lines of text, the textarea height is 3 rows?

It's part of an MVC application if that helps at all.  I'm using the html.textareafor as well.

Comment: It sounds like a `textarea` isn't the right fit. You don't want it to be edited and you want it to automatically size. Why not make it another element (`div`,`p`,`ul`,`table`, etc as appropriate).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Textarea Auto height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772260/textarea-auto-height)

Comment: Thanks Tim.  I was so set on using some sort of Control that using a p element didn't even enter in to my mind!

Answer (score 8):

Simplest I can think of is this:

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jats_ptl/zrx48kn1/)

```
div {
   display:inline-block;
   border: solid 1px #000;
   min-height:10px;
   width: 300px;
}
```

More Options:

- [Textarea Auto height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772260/textarea-auto-height)
- [Textarea to resize based on content length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995168/textarea-to-resize-based-on-content-length)

Comment: Working Fiddle is only working for Div only.not for text area

Comment: There are more links if those can help :)

Comment: So basically use a DIV tag instead. (The styles are unnecessary)

Answer (score 2):

More Smart Solution Of Mine depends On Count of Chars :) PHP Laravel

```
<textarea  class="form-control" name="description" id="description" style="height: {{(strlen($sectionItem->description)/4).'px'}}">{{$sectionItem->description}}</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

I do i similar in PHP but i use the rows and not the CSS Attribute:

```
<textarea class="form-control" type="text" rows="<?= strlen($sometext)/50 ?>" readonly> <?= strip_tags(nl2br($sometext)) ?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have spent the last hour reading sites, mostly SO, to find the answer to how to display HTML code on a page without it executing.
The best answer I found was to put it in a textarea, but the textarea did not expand vertically to show the entire contents. style='height:auto;' and style='height:fit-content;' did nothing.
So, my solution was (so simple it surprised me) - count lines (using '\n', the linefeed character in my text):

```
        <?php $lines = substr_count($HTML,"\n"); ?>
        <textarea style="border:none;width:100%;" rows="<?=$lines?>" ><?=$HTML?></textarea>
```

height is now perfect! Add disabled to textarea if you don't want it editable.

Comment: This is what the [`<pre>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) is for.