# Increase height of textarea with dynamic content on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have textarea, which will be auto-populated on page load. I'm trying to increase its height based of content loaded.

This is what i'm trying to do,

JS :

```
$('#xyz').text('dynamic content').attr('disabled',true);
textAreaModalAdjust(document.getElementById('xyz'));

function textAreaModalAdjust(o) {
        o.style.height = "1px";     
        setTimeout(function() {
            o.style.height = (25+o.scrollHeight)+"px";
        }, 1);
    }
```

Even, i tried without "setTimeout", no luck.

Comment: Looks like there is another thread that covers this on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454202/creating-a-textarea-with-auto-resize

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772260/textarea-auto-height   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25518182/textarea-autoheight-css   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995168/textarea-to-resize-based-on-content-length