# How to remove bottom padding in textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to remove bottom padding in `textarea` ?

```js
$('textarea').css("height", $("textarea").prop("scrollHeight"))
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 300px;
  resize: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a </textarea>
```

Comment: There is no padding, I cannot see it

Comment: which browser you are using?

Comment: You may want to look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995168/textarea-to-resize-based-on-content-length

Comment: maybe there is other css causing it, you must provide a live version w or a fiddle so we can reproduce the problem

Comment: The textarea `scrollheight` is measured **before** the heigh change making the scrollbar dissapear... Which make the textarea innerwidth a little bit larger... The text then wraps to take that scrollbar space in width, leaving some white space at the bottom. @Farid's solution is to prevent any scroll bar... So the measurement made before the height change is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use

overflow-y: hidden

as folows

```js
$('textarea').css("height", $("textarea").prop("scrollHeight"))
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 300px;
  resize: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a </textarea>
```