# How to adapt the size of a Textbox (MultiLine) to a text in ASP .NET C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have an .aspx form and in the *Page_Load* event I assign several values to controls (Textbox, DropdownList, etc.) from the database, however I have a Textbox control where it is possible that the text is very large or very small, it is here where I would like to know if it is possible to make the textbox size dynamic.

When the form finishes loading the Textbox control it is displayed like this:.

[image]

But I would like to visualize it like this (everything depends on the text):

[image]

Textbox Code:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="80px" ReadOnly="true" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
```

I am using .NET Framework 4.5.2, I am not sure if I should use any functionality from jQuery and if so, how would it be done?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textmode?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: ````TextMode="MultiLine"````

Comment: is multiline, i updated the question

Comment: That should render in the browser as a textarea if I recall... See this answer for dynamically finding the height...
https://stackoverflow.com/a/995374/3739842

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Textarea to resize based on content length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995168/textarea-to-resize-based-on-content-length)

Comment: @Sean T This works but I have to write about the textbox so that it changes the size ... The control has the property ReadOnly="true", therefore when I fear to load the form it must adapt automatically, I am seeing what I can do...

Comment: @Julián I'll add an answer

Comment: you know how to adapt the size when finish loading the form using the js code?

Comment: @Sean is the answer but the last part is missing xD

Comment: @Julián I've added an answer that includes both a pure javascript version and a version if you're using jQuery library

Comment: Use a different control. :\

Comment: <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with Javascript or Jquery on page load quite easily.

**Jquery:**

```
$(function(){//executes when dom is ready

    var textAreaAdjust = function(control) {//function to set the height
        $(control).height(1);
        $(control).height($(control).prop('scrollHeight'));
    }

    textAreaAdjust($('#txt'));// call the function passing the textarea control in
});
```

**Javascript:**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

        var textAreaAdjust = function(control){//funciton to measure and set height
            control.style.height = "1px";
            control.style.height = (25+control.scrollHeight)+"px";
        };

        var textControl = document.getElementById("txt");//get the textarea
        textAreaAdjust(textControl);//pass it into the function

}​);
```

Credit to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/995374/3739842)

Comment: It shows it totally minimized https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLcjk.png but when I call the function from the browser console it works, how strange

Comment: @Julián which version? javascript or jquery? I've changed the javascript event - that should fix it

Comment: i using the version 3.3.1

Comment: Sorry I meant which solution, I've posted 2 code snippets - which one are you using?

Comment: I'm using both, but they say scrollHeight is zero, that's why it minimizes it

Comment: Finally it worked, the error was mine, it turns out that the textbox is in a div that has a collapse behavior, it is for this reason that when the control was hidden the scrollHeight was always at zero but when it was displayed it showed the real value. Now I control it through a click event. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @Julián Glad you figured it out

Answer (score 0):

You could use a literal control

```
<asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

or an html div with `runat="server"` added.

```
<div id="specialDiv" runat="server"></div>
```

c#

```
specialDiv.InnerText = "asdfasdf...etc";
```

Note, if you use `CssClass="form-control"`, you might have to update the css by setting `height` to `auto`, instead of the preset/hard-coded height.