# How to separate css code blocks in javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, codeblocks

How to separate css code blocks in javascript?

Following are some css in the serialised form:

```
const css = "body { background-color: lightblue; } h1 { color: white; text-align: center; } p { font-family: verdana; font-size: 20px; }"
```

How can I parse it and get it in the following form as array (along with adding whitespaces (preserving whitespaces. i.e. in formatted form):

```
const parsedCss = [
'body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}',

'h1 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}',

'p {
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 20px;
}',

]
```

Comment: https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify/blob/master/README.md#web-library

Answer (score 2):

You could use `const parsedCss = css.split(/(?<=\})/)`

This splits the css on the  "}" symbol, and uses lookahead assertion to retain it.

The output would be

```
[
'body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}',

'h1 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}',

'p {
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 20px;
}',

]
```

Comment: How to add white spaces as in the above example? I mean to format it!

Comment: @mex Why do you want white spaces? It won't really make any difference..

Answer (score 1):

Try splitting with regex

```
/(?<=})\s+/
```

```js
const css = "body { background-color: lightblue; } h1 { color: white; text-align: center; } p { font-family: verdana; font-size: 20px; }"

const beautifiedCss = css_beautify(css)

const parsedCss = beautifiedCss.split(/(?<=})\s+/)

console.log(parsedCss.join(',\n\n'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-beautify/1.13.0/beautify-css.js"></script>
```

Comment: Shows error. Will this be able to add white spaces?

Comment: @mex at where you want to add spaces? Are you asking about formatting?

Comment: Yes. eXactly. I want it also be formatted. as well.

Comment: How can I do that also?

Comment: Ok. Thanks. One more help. How can I make the text area to show the whole content inside it. currently there is a scrollbar (overflow), instead I want it to grow and shrink according to the content inside. (I tried height 100%, then it grows and all other elements are hidden away from view. When I pul height auto then the text area  is taking some kind of minimal height. Instead I want it to fit the content

Comment: @mex what you are asking is irrelevant to this question. you can found that easily. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995168/textarea-to-resize-based-on-content-length

Answer (score 0):

```
const css =
  "body { background-color: lightblue; } h1 { color: white; text-align: center; } p { font-family: verdana; font-size: 20px; }";

let parsedCss = css
  .trim()
  .split("}")
  .map((word) => (word + "}").trim());
parsedCss.pop();

console.log(parsedCss);

/*
OUTPUT: 
[ 'body { background-color: lightblue; }',
  'h1 { color: white; text-align: center; }',
  'p { font-family: verdana; font-size: 20px; }' ]
*/
```

we can add `\n` for newline to get the formatted output:

```
const css =
  "body { background-color: lightblue; } h1 { color: white; text-align: center; } p { font-family: verdana; font-size: 20px; }";

let parsedCss = css
  .trim()
  .split("}")
  .map((word) =>
    (word.replace(/[;]/gi, ";\n").replace(/[{]/gi, "{\n") + "}")
      .trim()
      .toString()
  );
parsedCss.pop();

parsedCss.map((parsed) => console.log(parsed + ","));

/*
OUTPUT: 

body {
 background-color: lightblue;
 },
h1 {
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 },
p {
 font-family: verdana;
 font-size: 20px;
 },

*/
```

Comment: How to add white spaces as in the above example? I mean to format it!

Comment: @mex instead commenting in all answers. add all your constraints in question properly.

Comment: I mean inside the code blocks ```'h1 { color: white; text-align: center; }',``` how can I separate ```color``` ```text-align``` in to separate lines (I mean to add new line ). So that this would look much cleaner.