# Match the size of two textarea elements when one of them changes

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a small HTML page with two `textarea` elements side-by-side. One is enabled for input and the other is readonly and dynamically shows a preview for the first one (for some custom template processing).

[image: two textarea elements side-by-side]

I want both `textarea` elements to always have the same height and for them to match the other if the use resizes. I'm not using jQuery or any fancy JS framework, though I am using Bootstrap 5.

Can this be done with vanilla JS?

This is my code for the two `textarea`s:

```html
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 mb-3 form-floating mt-3 ml-auto gx-1">
            <textarea class="form-control" id="note_content" style="height: 300px"></textarea>
            <label for="note_content" class="form-label">Note content template (you can use book parameters here!)</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 mb-3 form-floating mt-3 ml-auto gx-1">
            <textarea class="form-control" id="note_content_preview" style="height: 300px" placeholder="preview" disabled></textarea>
            <label for="note_content_preview" class="form-label">Note content preview</label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: @naxsi added to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [resize observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver) to listen for resize changes on your main textarea element, and then adjust the height of your second textarea element based on the height/width of the first element by grabbing its height/width whenever it resizes:

```js
const note = document.getElementById("note_content");
const preview = document.getElementById("note_content_preview");

const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(() => {
 preview.style.height = note.offsetHeight + "px";
 preview.style.width = note.offsetWidth + "px";
});
resizeObserver.observe(note);
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6 mb-3 form-floating mt-3 ml-auto gx-1">
    <textarea class="form-control" id="note_content" style="height: 300px"></textarea>
    <label for="note_content" class="form-label">Note content template (you can use book parameters here!)</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 mb-3 form-floating mt-3 ml-auto gx-1">
    <textarea class="form-control" id="note_content_preview" style="height: 300px" placeholder="preview" disabled></textarea>
    <label for="note_content_preview" class="form-label">Note content preview</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want the textareas to match when either is ***resized*** you don't need any custom JS or CSS. In your markup use flexbox (`d-flex flex-column`) to make the textareas grow in height `flex-grow-1`...

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 mb-3 form-floating mt-3 ml-auto gx-1 d-flex flex-column">
            <textarea class="form-control flex-grow-1" id="note_content" style="height: 300px"></textarea>
            <label for="note_content" class="form-label">Note content template (you can use book parameters here!)</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 mb-3 form-floating mt-3 ml-auto gx-1 d-flex flex-column">
            <textarea class="form-control flex-grow-1" id="note_content_preview" placeholder="preview" disabled></textarea>
            <label for="note_content_preview" class="form-label">Note content preview</label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

If you also want the first textarea to resize to its content, use an input handler.

```
/* this is used to make 1st textarea resize to its content upon input */
const note_content = document.getElementById("note_content")
note_content.addEventListener("input", function(){
    this.style.height = "auto";
    this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight) + "px";
}, false)
```

https://codeply.com/p/scxO6z78dd

Answer (score -1):

```js
const noteContentElement = document.getElementById("note_content");
const noteContentPreviewElement = document.getElementById("note_content_preview");
noteContentElement.addEventListener('keyup', function(){
noteContentElement.style.height = (noteContentElement.scrollHeight > noteContentElement.clientHeight) ? (noteContentElement.scrollHeight)+"px" : noteContentElement.style.height+"px";
noteContentPreviewElement.style.height = noteContentElement.style.height;
noteContentPreviewElement.value = noteContentElement.value;
});

//Credits: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995168/textarea-to-resize-based-on-content-length
```

```css
.col-6{
width: 40%;
margin: 10px;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align:top;
}
.col-6 label{
display:block;
}
textarea{
overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 mb-3 form-floating mt-3 ml-auto gx-1">
            <textarea class="form-control" id="note_content"></textarea>
            <label for="note_content" class="form-label">Note content template (you can use book parameters here!)</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 mb-3 form-floating mt-3 ml-auto gx-1">
            <textarea class="form-control" id="note_content_preview"  placeholder="preview" disabled></textarea>
            <label for="note_content_preview" class="form-label">Note content preview</label>
        </div>
    </div>
```