# How to make the line break on enterkey in textarea

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I have a text area. Where On enter it gives me the perfect line break. But When I render it
in some templates it is not showing the line break. How can I rectify it? I don't want to use any jquery supported editor for that.

Comment: If you don't want jQuery, why did you add the `jquery` tag? Also, what on earth do you mean?

Comment: How are you rendering it? PHP, for example, has a function to convert newlines into html BR tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

welcome to Stackoverflow (SO). Information on subjects like this is easy to find here. Check [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47817/most-elegant-way-to-force-a-textarea-element-to-line-wrap-regardless-of-whites), or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863779/textarea-line-breaks-javascript). Next time, try searching SO first.

Answer (score 1):

The textarea gives you **text**, but presumably your templates are outputting **HTML**.

The text for a line break is `\n` but the HTML for a line break is `<br>`. You need to replace the former with the latter when converting between data formats.

(You also need to replace characters with special meaning in HTML (`<`, `>`, `&`, `'` and `"`) with their entity counterparts to avoid XSS problems)

Answer (score 0):

((What the hell is a perfect line break?))

I'm guessing that you have a text-area who's text you're saving and then showing it in a div or p or span, and you want the line-breaks to actually show.

There are three ways:

1. When saving/processing the text, do a search-and-replace for line break characters and replace them with the `<br />` element.
2. Style the element with the `white-space:pre;` style in CSS.
3. Wrap it all with the `<pre>` tag.