# wordwrap for textarea using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

I need functionality that `textarea` should contain max 5 lines and 
each line should contain max 15 chars, when user writes 2 words 
e.g. 123456 123456789 and if that line char limit exceeds 15, then 
it should bring the 2nd word in next line along with `\n` char in first line 
(means 123456 will be in first line along with `\n and 123456789` will be in 2nd)
, 
I need to maintain `\n`(replacing `<br`>) in my db for some reasons.

i wrote this code, which gives fuzzy result in some conditions

```
<textarea onkeypress="charCountTextarea('txt1',event,'75','14')" id="txt1"></textarea> 

var countLines=0;

var newLines;

function charCountTextarea(textAreaId,e,limit,lineLen)
{   

       newLines = $("#"+textAreaId).val().split("\n").length;
       var t = $("#"+textAreaId)[0];
       var lineIndex = t.value.substr(0, t.selectionStart).split("\n").length-1;

    //console.log("new lines"+lineIndex);
        if(newLines >= 5 && $("#"+textAreaId).val().split("\n")[lineIndex].length>lineLen)
        {

            if( e.keyCode!=8 && e.keyCode!=46 && e.keyCode!=33 && e.keyCode!=34 && e.keyCode!=35 && e.keyCode!=36 && e.keyCode!=37 && e.keyCode!=38 && e.keyCode!=39 && e.keyCode!=40)
            {
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        }


        else
        if($("#"+textAreaId).val().split("\n")[lineIndex].length>=lineLen)  // which will count the total line char condition
        {
            console.log($("#"+textAreaId).val().split("\n")[lineIndex][lineLen-1]);


            if($("#"+textAreaId).val().split("\n")[lineIndex][lineLen-1].indexOf(" ")==-1 && e.keyCode!=8 && e.keyCode!=46 && e.keyCode!=33 && e.keyCode!=34 && e.keyCode!=35 && e.keyCode!=36 && lineIndex != 4 && newLines<5)
            {
                // to bring the word in next line
                var str = $("#"+textAreaId).val(), replacement = '\n';
                str = str.replace(/ ([^ ]*)$/,replacement+'$1');
                $("#"+textAreaId).val(str);

            }
            else
            if(e.keyCode!=8 && e.keyCode!=46 && e.keyCode!=33 && e.keyCode!=34 && e.keyCode!=35 && e.keyCode!=36 && lineIndex!=4 && newLines<5)
            {
                // to insert next line              
                insertTextAtCaret(document.getElementById(textAreaId), "\n");
            }


        }

        if(e.keyCode == 13 && newLines >= 5) 
        {
            //linesUsed.css('color', 'red');
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }

}
```

Comment: Related CSS 3: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47817/most-elegant-way-to-force-a-textarea-element-to-line-wrap-regardless-of-white

Comment: i need to maintain \n , and with css it doesn't add \n for word wrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function charCountTextarea(textAreaId,e,limit,lineLen)
{   

    var code = e.charCode || e.keyCode;

    newLines = $("#"+textAreaId).val().split("\n").length;
    var t = $("#"+textAreaId)[0];
    var lineIndex = t.value.substr(0, t.selectionStart).split("\n").length-1;
    console.log('val t :'+$("#"+textAreaId).val()+' line index : '+lineIndex+' new lines '+newLines);

    if(lineIndex == 10 && $("#"+textAreaId).val().split("\n")[lineIndex].length>(lineLen+1) && code!=8 && code!=46 && code!=33 && code!=34 && code!=35 && code!=36 && code!=37 && code!=38 && code!=39 && code!=40)
    {
        $("#"+textAreaId).val(($("#"+textAreaId).val()).substring(0, $("#"+textAreaId).val().length - 1));
        alert('You are reached to limit');
        return false;
    }

    if(lineIndex<5)
    {
        $("#"+textAreaId).val($("#"+textAreaId).val().wordWrap(lineLen, "\n", 0));
    }
    var countLine1 = $("#"+textAreaId).val().split("\n")[0].length;

    if($("#"+textAreaId).val().split("\n")[lineIndex].length>lineLen)  // which will count the total line char condition
    {
        console.log("In condition : ");
        if(code!=8 && code!=46 && code!=33 && code!=34 && code!=35 && code!=36 && code!=37 && code!=38 && code!=39 && code!=40)
        {
            // to insert next line              
            insertTextAtCaret(document.getElementById(textAreaId), "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not know if the input will be fed using keyboard. I could just use the mouse to paste a text there.

I would rely on a function that would constantly check the input and take the action you want, which I would execute using the `setInterval()` function once the textarea is focused, which then gets cleared using `clearInterval()` once the textarea loses focus.

And this function would use a `RegExp` to process the input and split it into necessary lines.

**EDIT:** Here's what I mean.

```
$('body').on('focus','#txt1',function(e) {
    $(this).data('int',setInterval(checkInput,1));
}).on('blur','#txt1',function(e) {
    clearInterval($(this).data('int'));
    $(this).removeData('int');
});

function checkInput() {
    var val = $('#txt1').val();
    // process val here
    $('#txt1').val(val);
}
```

Comment: i dont want to lose the user's focus, whatever he types in textarea, should be as it is whatever he writes in it. thanks for suggestion

Comment: @SunilLohar I don't mean changing the focus. I edited my answer and added an example.

Comment: thanks for suggestion, i will check whether this work with your and my logic.