# Weird text wrap on textareas with IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

On IE11 / win7 64 I'm noticing a very weird pattern relating to how words wrap on a textarea.

Example:

[image: example]

http://fiddle.jshell.net/fy2aoz28/1/

With that text on the textarea, the second line is almost empty but it has space to at least have to "to :event_name" string.

On chrome that looks like this:

[image: chrome example]

So, what's going on here and is there any way to force all browsers on the same behavior?

Comment: Add `white-space: pre`. Meaning sequences of whitespace are preserved, lines are only broken at newline characters in the source and at <br> elements. http://fiddle.jshell.net/fy2aoz28/2/. Should look the same in IE and Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Add the `white-space` property. It is used to describe how whitespace inside an element is handled.

```
textarea{
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Should look the same in Chrome and IE now. Here's a fiddle for you to review. http://fiddle.jshell.net/fy2aoz28/2/

Comment: That's weird. I was reading from http://stackoverflow.com/a/20327197 and I tried with pre-wrap with no luck.  white-space: pre works and now chrome and IE works the same way. It seems pre-wrap or 'normal' don't work as supposed on IE11?  If someone can provide a more detailed explanation on what's going on here it will be appreciated... I solved the problem but don't understand the solution.

Comment: Chris Coyier provides a great explanation and gives examples. You can read it here: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/whitespace/. *White space using `pre` is honored exactly as it is in the HTML and the text does not wrap until a line break is present in the code.*

Comment: I didn't ask for it on the original question but so you know: on Firefox the display behavior is different, it's doesn't break lines

Comment: What version of Firefox? You might have to use `-moz` for earlier versions of Gecko. Like `textbox { white-space: pre; white-space: -moz-pre; ... }`

Comment: I think something changed Chrome in these months. Tested on 52.0.2743.116 and now using 'pre' in chrome causes the textarea to never wrap and only have content in 1 big line. IE 11 wraps the content just fine. Using pre-wrap causes again the different behaviour of IE and Chrome wrapping at different points.

Comment: OK, I can confirm that the behaviour of the fiddle changed on Chrome 49. After that version the textarea text doesn't wrap to multiple lines, instead being a single big line. On IE 11 it wraps. On Firefox  48.0.2 it's the same as Chrome.  So basically the answer doesn't work anymore :(