# Force line break in textarea

Tags: html, css, textarea

I have an issue with textarea angular tag, it is working different in ie11 and firefox/chrome. When I type a long text in chrome/firefox it automatically fit the text inside the textarea just like this:

[image: Chrome example]

But when I type the same text on ie11 it appears like this:

[image: IE example]

It is possible to make ie work like chrome/firefox?

The styling of the textarea its the following:

```
width: 380px;
height: 202px;
resize: none;
border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
border-radius: 2px;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried to set the textarea's `rows` and `cols` properties? also, maybe try different values for `overflow` style property too

Comment: Does the textarea have the `wrap` attribute set? Did you try explicitly specifying `white-space` for the textarea as well?

Comment: @CBroe I have set it, but it doesnt seem to work on IE

Comment: Please show an actual example where we can have a look at the issue. [mcve]

Comment: I dunno, but this springs to mind: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20149715/477453

Comment: @CBroe It seems to be something with angular, I have edited the answer. Because I have tried with html textarea tags and it works fine with ie 11

Comment: Try specifying the white-space property explicitly, see the question @SáT referred to for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @SáT pointed the solution was in that question (I have been looking in the comunnity but I did not found that question).

The solution is to add `white-space:pre-wrap`