# Text exceeded from content editable div on IE

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer

I have created a content editable div and the text is not wrapping to it.
I have tried to do "overflow:scroll" but it's just cutting the text on the X access.

[image: text axceeded]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20149715/internet-explorer-11-word-wrap-is-not-working i think here is answer, use `white-space: pre-wrap`

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

So the solution for me was simply:

word-break:break -all;