# Word wrapping on select in ie11

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11

Is there anyway to fix this? Ie11 only wants to display select menu's on one line which if fine....until the dropdowns get large.

In chrome, it behaves correctly.

[image: chrome]

but in ie it is displaying like a `white-space:nowrap;` has been applied.

[image: ie]

The only css that is being applied to the element is `width:100%;`

I have tried

```
white-space:normal; //all variations
overflow-wrap: normal; //all variations
word-wrap: break-word; //all variations
white-space: pre-wrap; //all variations
```

all separately, together or any combination.

Is there anyway to fix this and not go insane?

Comment: Does this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20327197/1839504) help?

Comment: @trevorp I have already seen that and unfortunately I have tried everything in there. Nothing worked for the select box

Comment: @zazvorniki have you managed to fix that layout issue in ie11 ?