# WBR Alternative in XHTML

Tags: html, css, xhtml, wbr

I've been using  tags in the thead cells for my tables, so I can control where browsers break long words.  This works great, but its not XHTML compliant.  What is the best alternative to using the wbr tag, that is valid XHTML?  Example:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>ThisIsAReally<wbr />LongWord<th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>...</td></tr>
    <tr><td>...</td></tr>
    <tr><td>...</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/904/in-html-how-to-word-break-on-a-dash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/oddsandends/wbr.html) has the solution