# Break non-hyphenated compound words at word boundary

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am using [Bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_%28front-end_framework%29). Let us say I have text that looks like this:

> "Stackoverflow"

Can I somehow automatically make sure that it breaks like this if the text does not fit the container:

> "Stack 
>   -overflow"

instead of:

> "Stackov 
>   -erflow"

with HTML/CSS?

Comment: i dont think theres any option for this

Comment: Doesn't it have to be `Stack-` and `overflow`? In Dutch that's the correct way, don't know in English btw...

Comment: Might be worth noting that if you're writing the name of SO in a document, it is actually named `Stack Overflow` (with a space), not `Stackoverflow` ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [In HTML, how to word-break on a dash?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/904/1048572)

Comment: For a start, the site is called "Stack Overflow", not "Stackoverflow", so you would simply break at the space.

Comment: Can we just assume that this is an example of a compound word, not the actual text, instead of telling OP that the problem is they're spelling Stack Overflow wrong? As a general question, I can see this being helpful to others.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can insert `&shy;` (soft hyphen)

```css
#box {
  font-size:14px;
  font-family:courier;
  width:90px;
  background:yellow;
 }
```

```html
<div id="box">Stack&shy;overflow</div>
```

Comment: If you can't use `&shy;` because you're not using some variant of (X)HTML (XML, Markdown, plain text…) you can use the equivalent Unicode character U+00AD (`&#x00ad;` in XML).

Answer (score 21):

You can use the `<wbr>` tag:

```css
p {
  width: 60px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<p>Stack<wbr>overflow</p>
```

Comment: This does not hyphenate the word break, I don't think this is what the OP is looking for.

Comment: You can add a hyphen at the wbr tag with css.

Answer (score 9):

No, for a document "Stackoverflow" is a single word. If you are using a CSS property to break the word then it will break according to the space available.

You have to define it if you want to break it from a particular point.

> You can use `Stack<wbr>overflow` or `Stack-overflow`.

If use `Stack<wbr>overflow`, then it will be broken at `<wbr>`.

```css
p.test1 {
    width: 60px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<p class="test1">Stack<wbr>overflow</p>
```

---

OR, if using `Stack-overflow` and using CSS property `word-break: keep-all;` then it will be broken at hyphens:

```css
p.test1 {
    width: 60px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    word-break: keep-all;
}
```

```html
<p class="test1">Stack-overflow</p>
```

**But you have to define one of them.**

Comment: `<wbr>` does not hyphenate the word break, I don't think that was asked for.

Comment: With the example with the dash (`-`), the dash appears even when the word fits.

Comment: @bergi thats why i have given another answer also

Answer (score 4):

If you want to break a *specific* word, then the answers given will work - insert an invisible break of some kind. It does, as pointed out, harm search results, but not so bad as you'd think.

If you want to break *all* compound terms that need wrapping, without manually going through and checking, then there is *no way to do this*, because you need context-sensitive English language parsing, which means you need a human brain doing it.

Consider how you would break the following strings:

```
lowrateslender.com
musictoyourears.com
heresearch.com
nakedsnow.com
picturespain.com
catspaying.net
attackshoes.com
williamsharp.net
andreward.net
goalsnow.net
hesstruck.net
artistrap.com
buildingskill.com
bearspray.com
atticsweep.com
matthewhale.com
singershaven.com
shoesworn.com
sinuscatscan.com
cometart.com
monkeyslap.com
scriptshack.com
nasalbum.com
moviesick.com
arizonasparesort.com
privateshot.com
nationsprinting.com
importcarshow.com
```

(copy-pasted from a google search for "ambiguous domain names")

...even given a dictionary to identify whole words within these terms, and inserting breaking spaces at those boundaries, it'd be a toss-up whether you would split these words as, say, "import-car-show" or "import-cars-how".

One of the main skills for programming is identifying algorithms which require natural language processing, and opting just for a "good enough" algorithm rather than wasting time on it. This is one such case.

Comment: Well that's exactly what `&shy;` is made for. It doesn't break search.

Comment: @Bergi What algorithm are you using to insert this in the right places? You end up with the same problem. Domains do not intrinsically contain `&shy;`.

Comment: `&shy;` is inserted by the *authors* in the HTML source, not by word-wrapping algorithms.

Comment: @Bergi In that case, I refer you to the first sentence of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use zero-width space, `&#8203;`. Just type `Stack&#8203;overflow` in HTML.

Comment: This solution really is the wrong one. It breaks search, for example.

Comment: Doesn't get more hacky than this.