# Break on hyphen instead of overflowing

Tags: html, css, hyphenation

I have a text inside a `div` with a hyphen in it. When the `div` gets too small, the text overflows instead of breaking at the hyphen.

I tried a bit with `word-break` and `overflow`, but couldn't figure out how to make the text break *only* at the hyphen. Here is an example of what is happening, and what I am trying to achieve.

```css
div{
  width:70px;
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<b>How it is now </b>
<div> bla bla-blablabla</div>
<br>

<b> What should happen: </b>
<div> bla bla-<br>blablabla</div>
```

Edit for the duplicate question:
The answers given there are wrong.

1. The best (by votes) answer suggests replacing hyphens by `&shy;`. This is incorrect, since those hyphens will NOT show up when there is no line break.
2. The second answer suggests `<wbr>`, but this is not supported in all browsers.
3. The third best answer suggests CSS word-wrapping, which does not make it break at hyphens.

Comment: its already breaking in your snippet

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In HTML, how to word-break on a dash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/904/in-html-how-to-word-break-on-a-dash)

Comment: @GauravAggarwal then it probably doesn't break for every browser, dont you think?

Comment: @blonfu Thank you for your suggestion. I checked that page, but the above two answers are not correct. The first one uses shy hyphens, which will not show up when there is no line break, and the second uses word break all, which also gives another result. The other answers also don't give a full solution for all browsers.

Comment: is possible use javascript?

Answer (score 1):

use `word-wrap: break-word` and will break when there is no more space. not when "we" want.

```css
div {
  width: 70px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
div:first-of-type {
  word-wrap: break-word
}
```

```html
<b>How it is now </b>
<div>bla bla-blablabla</div>
<br>

<b> What should happen: </b>
<div>bla bla-
  <br>blablabla</div>
```

**UPDATE** due to you really want to break **only** in `hyphen` you can use either `&shy;` or `wbr`

```css
div {
  width: 70px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<b>How it is now </b>
<div>bla bla-blablabla</div>
<br>

<b> What should happen: </b>
<div>bla bla-
  <br>blablabla</div>

<hr />
<b>How it is now using &amp;shy;</b>
<div>bla bla&shy;blablabla</div>
<br>

<b>How it is now using wbr</b>
<div>bla bla-<wbr>blablabla</div>
<br>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. In firefox, it breaks during the second word, but not on the hyphen.

Comment: @user4493177 as I said, it will break where is no more space to write. if you change the words, you will see what I'm talking about

Comment: Right, but the question was about breaking on hyphen. I know what word break does, but it is no solution for this question. Same goes for shy, it is simply no answer to this question. Only wbr provides the desired solution, but lacks support in internet explorer (before IE 12).

Comment: @user4493177 why `&shy;` it is no solution for you? it is replacing the hyphen, and as you already said you want to **break only** when there is an **hyphen**

Comment: With shy, the hyphen is not visible when there is no line break.

Comment: You won't find a bullet proof solution using only CSS for cross browser compatible

Comment: Is curious, in IE `<wbr>` works only with a `-` before, but not with others characters.

Answer (score 0):

With jquery if you can use:

```js
$(function() {
$('div').each(function() {
  $(this).html($(this).text().replace(/-/, '-<br>'));
});
});
```

```css
div{
  width:80px;
  border:solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div> bla bla-blablabla blablabla-blabla</div>
```

**UPDATE**

```js
$('div').each(function() {
  $(this).html($(this).text().replace(/-/g, '<span></span>'));
});
```

```css
div{
  width:80px;
  border:solid 1px red;
}

span:after{
  content:"-";
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div> bla bla-blablabla babababs sbba-blabla</div>
```

Comment: doesn't this simple replace all - by -<br>, therefore also inserting newlines when the div is wide enough to show everything on one line?

Comment: I edit my answer. Maybe is better put the hypen in the `span` and remove from `content`, because in `content` isn`t selectable.