# Preventing hyphenated words from breaking separately on overflow

Tags: html, css, overflow, css-hyphens

I have the following simple code that limits text to two lines and displays an ellipsis to indicate more content exists if applicable.

I have an issue however that hyphenated words such as "breath-taking" are not being treated as one word, and is (depending on view size) often appearing as "breath-..." at the end of the second line.

Either the entirety should be shown "breath-taking", or none at all.

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 350px;
}

p {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;

  white-space: unset;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>
    Take to the skies to experience the breath-taking views.
    Take to the skies to experience the breath-taking views. Take to the skies to experience the breath-taking views.
  </p>
</div>
```

I have investigated the option of using `&shy;`, various `hyphen` properties and the popular question on SO: [How to break word after special character like Hyphens (-)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904/how-to-break-word-after-special-character-like-hyphens) but to no avail, any insight would be appreicated

Comment: You might want to try using the non-breaking hyphen, `&#8209;` instead of any of the variations on a normal hyphen.

Comment: ah - thank you both! that has caused may way more time and pain that it should have!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a non-breaking hyphen `&#8209;` or `&#x2011;`

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 350px;
}

p {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;

  white-space: unset;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>
    Take to the skies to experience the breath&#8209;taking views.
    Take to the skies to experience the breath&#8209;taking views. Take to the skies to experience the breath-taking views.
  </p>
</div>
```